# Core Data issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am working with core data app and my query is that I have a child and parent relationship with the parent relationship having inverse relationship with the child and in the parent entity with To many relationship checked,

So now my query is that I want to access the name of the parent lets say mother name by just giving the child name so i am using predicate for this here's a view at my code

```
-(void)retrieveviaPredicate
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" 
                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Childname=='ravi'"];
    [fetchReq setPredicate:pred];
    NSArray *t = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchReq error:nil];

    for(Child *p in t)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",p.Childname);

        for(Parent *p1 in p.childToParent)
        {
        NSLog(@"Mother name is %@",p1.MotherName);
        }
    }       
}
```

In the above code I am getting a warning which says that

```
warning:  NSManagedObject' may not respond to '-countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:
```

and when I run the app the app goes south, could you please help me out on this

Thanks and Regards

Radix

Comment: Dear Radix, please learn to format the question properly. You can see how it's done by clicking the "edit" entry above.

Comment: And please post your header file for the class `Parent`.

Comment: @Yuji: already done that bro and this is just a part of the code that i am displaying already added the header for Parent and Child. And yes i will format my questions properly.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `childToParent` is a to-many relationship. I guess it's not.

---

the for loop would only work if it would be a to-many relationship:

```
for(Parent *p1 in p.childToParent)
```

EDIT:

what happens if you replace

```
for(Parent *p1 in p.childToParent)
{
    NSLog(@"Mother name is %@",p1.MotherName);
}
```

with

```
NSLog(@"Mother name is %@",p.childToParent.MotherName);
```

Comment: no its not, ParentToChild is a too many relationship, but i want to get the mother name by using the child name, i got the child name if i am giving any one of the parent name

Comment: @Radix you can't use enumeration (the for loop) on to-one relationships. Because there is no set of objects, there is just one object at the other end. See my edit.

Comment: Eureka got that done what i did is this    for(Child *p in t)
 {
  NSLog(@"%@",((Parent*)(p.childToParent)).MotherName);
 }

Answer (score 0):

I had this warning when relationship was set 1 - to - 1, not 1 - to - many. Fixing relationship type fixed the issue.